# PrimeFaces: which ajax event do I need?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have this `commandButton`:

```
<p:commandButton value="View/Edit" onclick="bar.show()"
                 oncomplete="bar.hide(); dataSetUserDialog.show();"
                 actionListener="#{dataStoreBean.initUserLists}">
    <p:ajax event="?" update="userSelect" ></p:ajax>
    <f:param name="checkSum" value="#{dataSet.checkSum}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

And this `dialog` with a `selectManyMenu` inside:

```
<p:dialog header="View or Edit #{dataStoreBean.currentDataSetName} users"
          widgetVar="dataSetUserDialog" modal="true" width="500" height="200">
    <h:form>
        <p:selectManyMenu id="userSelect" value="#{dataStoreBean.selectedUsers}" style="width: 475px;">
            <f:selectItems value="#{dataStoreBean.users}"
                           var="user" itemValue="#{user.email}"
                           itemLabel="#{user.email} | #{user.groupName}" />
        </p:selectManyMenu>

        <p:commandButton value="Done"
                         actionListener="#{dataStoreBean.updateDataSetsUsers}"            
                         onclick="dataSetUserDialog.hide()" type="submit" />
    </h:form>

</p:dialog>
```

What I want to achieve is to have updated info in the dialog I want to show. `userSelect` is inside that dialog. So first I want `#{dataStoreBean.initUserLists}` to execute, and after that update (rerender) `userSelect`, and then show `dataSetUserDialog`. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you've all already tried and why they are insufficient, but what's wrong with the default event, `action`? I.e. just remove `event` attribute altogether.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks, I should really learn / memorize the JSF lifecycle sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As BalusC suggested, I should use `action` instead of `actionListener`:

```
<p:commandButton value="View/Edit users" onclick="loadNotification.show()"
                 oncomplete="loadNotification.hide(); dataSetUserDialog.show();"
                 action="#{dataStoreBean.initUserLists}" update="userSelect">
    <f:param name="checkSum" value="#{dataSet.checkSum}" />
    <f:param name="fullFileName" value="#{dataSet.fileName}.#{dataSet.fileType}" />
</p:commandButton>

<p:dialog id="userSelect" draggable="false" resizable="false"
          header="View or Edit #{dataStoreBean.currentDataSetName} users"
          widgetVar="dataSetUserDialog" modal="true" width="500" height="200">
    <h:form>
        <p:selectManyMenu value="#{dataStoreBean.selectedUsers}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{dataStoreBean.users}" var="user"
                           itemValue="#{user.email}"
                           itemLabel="#{user.email} | #{user.groupName}" />
        </p:selectManyMenu>

        <p:commandButton value="Done"
                         actionListener="#{dataStoreBean.updateDataSetsUsers}" 
                         update="dataSetMessages"
                         onclick="dataSetUserDialog.hide()" type="submit" />
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```